# Hosting a create-react-app in a subdirectory of vite-react-app

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, create-react-app, subdirectory, vite

I'm working on my portfolio site which is Vite + ReactJS website. On my portfolio website I would like to preview different projects I have done with a possibility to open that project in the browser. I would like these projects to be hosted on the same domain as the portfolio, so when project1 is visited it would be something like [www.mydomain.com/Projects/project1](http://www.mydomain.com/Projects/project1). Project1 is create-react-app, build with npm run build.

The problem however, is when project1 is opened, and there has been done some routing (using react-router-dom) and you refresh the page it becomes a blank page.

I hope, my explanation makes sense ?

Link to minimal demo (sorry for the lack of styling btw.): https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-react-projects-in-subdirectory-of-root-77s9fn

Project1 - .env.production:

```
PUBLIC_URL=/Projects/project1
```

Project1 - app.js

```
  import logo from './logo.svg';
  import './App.css';

    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    import About from './assets/pages/About';
    import Home from './assets/pages/Home';
    import Contact from './assets/pages/Contact';
    
    function App() {
    
      return (   
    
          <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
            <ul>
    
              <li><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
              <li><NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink></li>
              <li><NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
    
            </ul>
    
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
              <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
    
            </Routes>
    
          </Router>
      )
    }

export default App;
```

Comment: In the demo provided on codesandbox.io, the project launches. I go to project1, click all the links, click the refresh button to the left of the address bar. The page goes back to the landing page.  This seems to be the result you desire. I do not see, or understand, the problem.